# Html display a legend

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on a leaflet map and i want to add a legend on it by using a modal to do that.

In my modal i want to use a :

```
<ul><li>
```

and each ligne of my ul can be an horizontal line with a text or an icon with a text.

exemple :

`-----(red) : Polyline of users`

`-----(green) : Polyline of the race`

`(icon) : marker of users ....`

I don't know how to draw a red line in html/css to do something like that.

I have tried the `<hr>` but it's always take all the line.

thanks for your help.
I include the code of my modal :

```
<div id="infoModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Informations</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2>Legende : </h2>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <hr width="25%" size="10">
                            </div>
                            <div class ="col-md-8">
                                TEST
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Example** (From Comment Section)

[image]

Comment: How is this supposed to look...it's not clear?

Comment: something lik that http://cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/5142736/original/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-25%20at%206.14.11%20AM.png?1366895814
but only with one clumn

Comment: I would imagine the best way to go about that is by using pictures for each icon including the lines.

Comment: A table might be more appropriate here.

Comment: You can try to add `<span class="line red"></span>` and with css to make it looks cool.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox and a pseudo-element.

```css
.list-group-item {} .list-group-item div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.list-group-item div::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal-body">
  <h2>Legende : </h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-25-25-2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
.my-divider {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

.my-divider::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 my-divider">TEST</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Values are a bit arbitrary so change those to suit.